# C# Lists => Remove objects where a property does not exist in another list

Tags: c#-4.0, ilist, icollection

I have 2 lists of the same type (Results). 
Both lists are populated with a unique data set but may or may not contain a common property ex: (Results.TitleName).

My question is, with an ICollection returned for each list, how can I remove items from each list where the other list does not contain Results.TitleName.

Any help would be appreciated. But keep in mind that I could be dealing with a rather large data set so performance should be considered.

```
var Results1 = ResultsRepository.GetPoints(FirstElement);

var Results2 = ResultsRepository.GetPoints(SecondElement);
```

---

```
public ICollection<Results> GetPoints(string element)
{
  if (element == null)
  {
    //Exception
  }

  using (ISession session = OpenSession())
  {
    try
    {
      return session.CreateQuery(HQL Query)
        .List<Results>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      //Exception
    }
  }
```

### }

ResultsRepository is a NHibernate Domain:
    using System;

```
public class Results
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique Sample Number
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string SampleNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Result Title name
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string TitleName{ get; set; }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: You should post the code you are working with.  It's much easier to show you how to tweak something that isn't working than to show an example from a blank slate.

Comment: I have added code snippets to the initial post.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
List<Results> list1 = ...;
List<Results> list2 = ...;
list1.Remove(x => !list2.Any(y => y.TitleName != x.TitleName);
```

If you have an extremely large dataset this lookup may be too slow and hence a `HashSet<T>` may be preferable.

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(list2.Select(x => x.TitleName);
list1.Remove(x => !set.Contains(x.TitleName));
```

Comment: I'm missing something here, the x.TitleName isn't valid in either scenario. Any ideas?

Comment: @AllStar11 can you post the definition to `Result` so that we can see how to get from them to `TitleName`?

Comment: Done. Please see the edits in the initial post.
Cheers!

Comment: @AllStar11 renamed to use the type `Results` instead of `Result`

Comment: I still cannot access any members of x in the following snippet:

y => y.TitleName != x.TitleName

OR

!set.Contains(x.TitleName)

Comment: @AllStar11 what happens when you try?  It works fine on my test setup

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48616/discussion-between-allstar11-and-jaredpar)

Comment: I receive the following errors:

Error 11 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Results' because it is not a delegate type 
Error 12 The name 'Results2' does not exist in the current context